# what is the keyword that allow me to implement an abstract class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

what is the keyword that allow me to implement an abstract class?
It was asked in my interview..
Can you say it from both java and ActionScript(flex)

Answer (score 0):

That for Java would be `extends` like:

```
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass { }
```

ActionScript 3 does not support abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pseudo abstract class (I know, its not the same, but it helps in some cases). We add the word abstract to the start of the class name, and then use getqualifiedclass name to stop instances of the class being created.

This guy explains it well:
http://joshblog.net/2007/08/19/enforcing-abstract-classes-at-runtime-in-actionscript-3/